# for-loop does not terminate

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out why my innermost `for` loop does not break.
I have implemented a *Caesar cipher* for a "list" of `char` arrays.

```c
void caesar(char **list, size_t listsize, unsigned int offset) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < listsize; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; list[i] != NULL && j < sizeof(list[i]); j++) {
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < offset && (list[i][j] >= 65 && list[i][j] <= 90) || (list[i][j] >= 97 && list[i][j] <= 122); k++) {
                if(list[i][j] == 122)
                    list[i][j] = 97;
                else if(list[i][j] == 90)
                    list[i][j] = 65;
                else
                    list[i][j]++;

                //works with the break condition
/*                if(k == offset - 1)
                    break;*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So without the last `break` statement I get an endless loop, even though I have a `break` condition in the head of my `for` loop.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: given `char **list`, you have `sizeof(list[i])` which evaluates the size of a pointer... probably not what you want.

Comment: You probably want `strlen(list[i])`

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it. But the code worked with sizeof(list[i]). Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for (unsigned int k = 0; k < offset && (list[i][j] >= 65 && list[i][j] <= 90) || (list[i][j] >= 97 && list[i][j] <= 122); k++)
> ```

Using some placeholder identifiers, the loop condition is written in the form `a && b || c`, which due to operator precedence is parsed as `(a && b) || c` and not the `a && (b || c)` you intend. You can add some parentheses to fix it:

```
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < offset && ((list[i][j] >= 65 && list[i][j] <= 90) || (list[i][j] >= 97 && list[i][j] <= 122)); k++)
//                                     ^                                                                                 ^
```